# Is there a (RESTful) API for the linux man pages?

Tags: linux, api, rest, manpage

I'm looking for a way to query the linux man pages through an API, the closest I've found is http://linux.die.net/man, however there the commands are split into 8 sections, e.g. gcc is in section 1: http://linux.die.net/man/1/gcc, and as it's not actually an API so you get a full html page (sidebar and ads included) in return.

Before I plough on and try to make one, does something like this already exist?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why not just use your local man pages? Man pages are just compressed text files of nroff source code. nroff is confusing and weird, but should be doable. A man page [creation guide](http://www.fnal.gov/docs/products/ups/ReferenceManual/html/manpages.html) should make it clear.

For the location of the files, use `man -w COMMAND`. On my machine `man -w man` gives me `/usr/share/man/man1/man.1.gz`. So my man files are stored in the subdirectories of `/usr/share/man`. Probably would be easy to index from there.

If you look hard enough, someone probably already wrote a man page parser.

Comment: Yep, this looks like the best route. Annoyingly searching for man page parsers returns man pages about parsers :)
Thanks, Phil

Comment: The creation guide link says, that the info is deprecated.

Comment: Parser for troff/groff files: https://www.npmjs.org/package/manolo

Answer (score 0):

Yes this seems to work.

```
[root@test~]# man -w ls
/var/cache/man/cat1/ls.1.lzma (<-- /usr/share/man/man1/ls.1.gz)
[root@test ~]#
```

You can also check online man pages at http://www.go2techschool.com/linux-all-commands.php

Comment: Sadly, this link is dead, too. (As in the accepted answer)